# Write video with opencv with fourcc H264: Cannot load libcuda.so.1

Tags: python, opencv, video, h.264

I'm trying to create a video using opencv-python. I have to use H.264 codec for my video so I have the following lines:

```
import cv2


width = ...
height = ...
name = ...

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
self.video = cv2.VideoWriter(name, fourcc, 30, (width, height))
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
[h264_nvenc @ 0x562490d62d80] Cannot load libcuda.so.1
Could not open codec 'h264_nvenc': Unspecified error
```

As I see in the error, I need `libcuda.so.1` library which comes with nvidia driver afaik, but my laptop has no dedicated graphic card.

Is it possible to write a video using H.264 using my laptop? If yes, please advice how. Thank you!

Comment: Why must you use that codec? Here are all the possible codecs you can use: http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php . Also on this page it says the different codecs the work fine for them in different OS https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: If you want to use it you can download the codec from http://www.fourcc.org/downloads/h264-unknown-10/

Comment: @Ben10, I forgot to specify that I'm using Linux. The link from your second comment does not provide a Linux version of the codec.

I have to use the H264 standard because my video-editor-friend for whom I have to make this video asked for H264. I'm not familiar with video stuff, it's my first try of this kind, but I've read that it's the best codec out there.